# JQuery Noty with Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a notification using JQuery, Noty in my CodeIgniter Project.

I Used the following Script Code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
<?php
 if (!empty($noti)) {
    foreach ($noti as $ns) {
        $date = new DateTime($ns->increment_date);

    }
 }

?>
noty({text: 'The Increment Date of', layout: 'center', closeWith: ['click', 'hover'], type: 'success'});
     });

</script>
```

## Model

```php
<?php

class Welcome_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }


    function increment_date(){

        $this->db->select('title, initials, last_name, increment_date');
        $this->db->from('tbl_officer');
        $this->db->where('tbl_officer.status=1 and  str_to_date(concat(increment_date,'-',year(curdate())),"%d-%b-%Y")
           between curdate() and curdate() + interval 30 day');
        $query=  $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
        }
    }    

}
```

The code is working fine and out the notification, "**The Increment Date of**". But I want to outs the value of `$ns->increment_date` at the end of this text. When I add `$ns->increment_date` as `'The Increment Date of <?=$ns->increment_date?>'` in the text, the noty is not working.

What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Move your `php` block before the JS Block.

Comment: @ascsoftw. But didn't work

Comment: Check the console to see the error. Check how the view source looks.

Comment: @ ascsoftw. If I used 'The Increment Date of <?php= $ns->increment_date ?>', the code outs The Increment Date of increment_date ?>

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reformat the code as below:

```
<?php
    $date = ''; //Define an empty value
    if (!empty($noti)) {
        foreach ($noti as $ns) {
            $date = new DateTime($ns->increment_date);
        }
    }

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 

var date = '<?php echo $date; ?>';//Pass the value from PHP to JS and pass below.

noty({text: 'The Increment Date of ' + date , layout: 'center', closeWith: ['click', 'hover'], type: 'success'});
     });

</script>
```

Comment: But the increment_date hasn't year. eg :- 10-Nov, 20-Nov

Comment: Please specify the format of `$ns->increment_date` and the output you want.

Comment: I meant what is the actual value in this variable and how do you want it to be displayed.

Comment: @ ascsoftw. Actual values are 10-Nov, 20-Nov in this variable and I want to display, "The Increment Date of 10-Nov" and "The Increment Date of 20-Nov" etc...

Comment: @mcode Then this should be working. Please check if there is any error in console and also check how the view source looks.

Comment: @mcode Please check the view source, how does it looks like.

Comment: @ ascsoftw. My model also added

Comment: You should be able to check the Source Code of the Page and debug it from there. Check what is the value of `$date` in PHP, then check if its passed to JS and see how the `text` passed to noty looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201759/discussion-between-mcode-and-ascsoftw).